# Brain damage / change in long term psychiatric conditions such as schizophrenia

Tags: psychiatry, schizophrenia

There seems to be evidence to suggest that long term psychiatric conditions have effects on grey matter in the brain and the development of certain sections of the brain.

Do antipsychotics have a protective effect on the brain against the degenerative effects of schizophrenia relapse?

I have found many academic papers both supporting and contradicting a protective effect, but finding an agreed upon consensus is difficult. I'm also looking for evidence indicating what effect a schizophrenic relapse has on the brain and the exact degenerative effects that occur.

Comment: After my edit, this appears to be a duplicate of your other question: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/6090/what-are-the-effects-of-antipsychotic-medication-on-brain-volume

Comment: @what Thanks for the edit. The two questions are very much linked you are correct but they are different questions. One is asking what the effect of antipsychotic medication is on the brain and the other is asking what effect the illness has on the brain. Personally I consider them separate questions but if you'd rather see them merged I'd understand.